# Is there a way to run completely different projects written in different languages on the same domain/server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, reverse-proxy, portfolio

Im currently in the fourth semester of my bachelors degree at university and i have a couple projects i am proud of. As a side project I'm developing a small portfolio website using react as a way to show potential employers what I've learned at uni.

So my index and "about me" section will be made using react. But let's say my dream website has a button/module which would take you to one of the projects i worked on last semester. 
The project I'm thinking of was written using .net mvc and entity framework.

Another project could be some php website, and a third button would take you to another project made using Angular + .net core. I haven't started tackling this issue yet because i'd imagine theres a specific way to approach it, and I really have no idea where to start. I'd imagine there's some routing magic involved, but other than that I'm in the dark. I've read a bit about reverse proxies which seemed to be related to my problem. However i was unable to replicate their solution because of inexperince.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reverse proxy is the right keyword here. I would suggest something like NGINX which you can then configure to proxy to your projects like that:

```
location /angular {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}

location /react {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

You can then browse your different applications with http://yourwebserver/angular and http://yourwebserver/react